# Picture will not appear

Tags: html, image

I am brand new to coding and have not been able to determine why two seemingly identical pieces of code do not work the same. This exercise involves simply making a picture appear on a web page. Easy enough, but I do not see why the same code only works one out of two times.

This code works:

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <div>
                img class="img-responsive" src="http://pre10.deviantart.net/1d23/th/pre/i/2013/070/1/e/grumpy_cat_by_bwcopy-d5xod2v.jpg"
            </div>
```

While this code does not:

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <div>
                img class="img-responsive" src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-04/21/16/enhanced/webdr05/enhanced-31550-1429646952-7.jpg"
            </div>
```

I checked the source for the non-working photo and it is valid. (Check it yourself if you like ultra-cute puppies).

What am I not seeing? (besides the puppy picture, obviously).

Thanks.

Comment: Think you're missing the opening and closing brackets of `img`: `<img ...>`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `img` tag, you are just writing plain text.

Change to this (notice the brackets):

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://pre10.deviantart.net/1d23/th/pre/i/2013/070/1/e/grumpy_cat_by_bwcopy-d5xod2v.jpg" />
```

First and 2nd code snippets look the same, no reason either of them should work.

Comment: Thanks Omri. Perhaps I should have mentioned that this is a debugging exercise.  The working code and non-working code to two early identical websites are to be compared and fixes made.  I fixed everything other piece but this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
      <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="well text-center">
    <div>
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://pre10.deviantart.net/1d23/th/pre/i/2013/070/1/e/grumpy_cat_by_bwcopy-d5xod2v.jpg">
    </div>
```

or this:

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="well text-center">
    <div>
     <img class="img-responsive" src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-04/21/16/enhanced/webdr05/enhanced-31550-1429646952-7.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abood.  Adding angle brackets to the non-working (dog) code worked.  My question is why, since they are not present in the working (cat) code. Does the dog image being located on an https url require angle brackets while the cat image's url is http does not? Thanks for your help.

Comment: both of it cat and dog images are not displayed until you add angel brackets  to it!!!